# Fetch data from Airtable with pyairtable, formula that combines NOT with another argument

Tags: python, airtable

I'm using pyairtable to fetch data from an Airtable with Python.

Both #1 and #2 work fine.
I'm looking for a solution to combine the two formulas.
I need one formula that would give the results matching column1 = string1 and column2 not empty.

```
from pyairtable import Table
from pyairtable.formulas import match
table = Table(API_KEY, BASE_ID, TABLE_ID)

#1
formula = match({"column1": "string1"})
results = table.all(formula=formula, fields=['field1'])

#2
formula = "NOT({column2}='')"
results = table.all(formula=formula, fields=['field1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `NOT()` in pyairtable but should be very easy to do with just plain text using [Airtable Formulas](https://support.airtable.com/docs/formula-field-reference) `AND` and `NOT`

```
formula = "AND({column1}='John',NOT({column2}=''))"
table.all(formula=formula, fields=['field1'])
```

[Formula Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sO2s.png)
[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv0oT.png)